# Where does this theorem of Ogg appear?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The webpage [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~asnowden/teaching/2013/679/L20.html](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Easnowden/teaching/2013/679/L20.html) claims that Ogg proved that the order of $[0] - [\infty]$ on $J_0(N)$ is $(N-1)/\gcd(N-1, 12).$ I cannot find any paper of Ogg that seems to prove this result, and was wondering if anyone knew a reference.